Mokṣa and Rebirth in Gītā and the Upaniṣads
Namaste.
I wanted to know about the similarities between the concepts of Mokṣa and Rebirth discussed in the Gītā and Upaniṣads.
As it is said :
sarvopanishado gavo dogdha gopalanandana:
parthovatsa: sudheerbhoktha dugdham gitamrutam mahat
All upanishads are cows. The milker is the son of the cowherd, Krishna; Arjuna, son of prutha, is the calf;
the men of
purified intellect are the drinkers and the milk is the supreme
nectar of Gita.
So , the Gītā and Upaniṣads as we know mostly say the same things.
I would like to know the similarities between how Mokṣa and Rebirth are discussed in the Gītā and Upaniṣads.
Thanks.
